# Code does not print whole data in an output file

Tags: c#, .net, xz

when I run this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        var searchDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(currentDirectory);

        var queryMatchingFiles =
                from file in searchDirectory.GetFiles()
                let fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file.Name)
                select file.Name;

        StreamWriter outputCacheMeta = new StreamWriter(@"output.txt");

        foreach (var fileName in queryMatchingFiles.Where(fileName => !fileName.EndsWith(".txt") && !fileName.EndsWith(".exe") && !fileName.EndsWith(".xz")))
        {
            // start the converion utility
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = "xz.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = "-k -z " + fileName;
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

            using (Process p = Process.Start(startInfo))
            {
                while (!p.HasExited)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(300);
                }
            }

            //Process.Start(startInfo);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Compressing file: '{0}'", fileName.ToString()));

            // generate final string
            FileInfo inFile = new FileInfo(fileName);
            FileInfo outFile = new FileInfo(fileName + ".xz");

            outputCacheMeta.WriteLine("<ContentFile Name=\"" + fileName.ToString() + "\" Size=\"" + inFile.Length.ToString() + "\" SHA1Hash=\"" + HashCalc.GetSHA1Hash(fileName).ToString() + "\" CompressedSize=\"" + outFile.Length.ToString() + "\" />");
            //Console.WriteLine(string.Format(("<ContentFile Name=\"" + fileName.ToString() + "\" Size=\"" + inFile.Length.ToString() + "\" SHA1Hash=\"" + HashCalc.GetSHA1Hash(fileName).ToString() + "\" CompressedSize=\"" + outFile.Length.ToString() + "\" />")));
        }
    }
```

it does not print everything in the output file (output.txt), it prints this: http://pastebin.com/1vTQZVih (sorry for external link).

The problem is that it suddenly 'stops' writing to the output file.

Thanks!

Comment: add a outputCacheMeta.Flush(); at the end (but inside) the foreach loop

Comment: Have you debugged and stepped through the code to see what's stopping it?

Comment: how big is patch_survival.ff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not `Flush()`ing or `Close()`ing your `StreamWriter` before your program exits.  Some of your file data is buffered to be written to the file, but will not actually get written until your flush and and close the stream.